# How to get both value and text of angular material multi selection field

Tags: angular, dropdown

I need to select both `value and its text` from Angular material multiple selection option. I am explaining my code below.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>Grade</mat-label>
     <mat-select
        placeholder="Grade" 
        aria-label="Grade"
        formControlName="Grade"
        (selectionChange)="selectedGrade($event)"
        multiple
        required
     >
     <mat-option *ngFor="let s of gradeCodes" [value]="s.Code">
          <span *ngIf="!s.Name">
          </span>
          <span *ngIf="s.Name">
              {{s.Name}}
          </span>
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

selectedGrade(event: any) {
    console.log('event', event);
    let target = event.source.selected[0]._element.nativeElement;
    let value = event.value[0];
    let obj = {
      code: value,
      level: target.innerText.trim()
    }
    this.selectedLevel.push(obj);
    console.log('grade', this.selectedLevel);
  }
```

Here I my drop down has multiple select option. I need when user will select the first value from dropdown then the related `value and text` will push into another array but as per my case same value is coming in each selection.

Comment: Could you please share `gradeCodes` object a sample for me ?

Comment: @errorau: `this.gradeCodes=[{Name:'Nurserry',Code:'A'},{Name:'Grade1',Code:'B'},{Name:'Grade2',Code:'C'}]`. This is one sample fdata.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes

```
 <mat-option *ngFor="let s of gradeCodes" [value]="s">
```

You need to use **compareWith** property for mat-select [compareWith documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#caveat-option-selection)

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>Grade</mat-label>
     <mat-select
        placeholder="Grade" 
        aria-label="Grade"
        formControlName="Grade"
        (selectionChange)="selectedGrade($event)"
        multiple
        required
     >
     <mat-option *ngFor="let s of gradeCodes" [value]="s">
          <span *ngIf="!s.Name">
          </span>
          <span *ngIf="s.Name">
              {{s.Name}}
          </span>
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

selectedGrade(event: any) {
    console.log('event', event);
    let target = event.source.selected[0]._element.nativeElement;
    let value = event.value[0];
    let obj = {
      code: value,
      level: target.innerText.trim()
    }
    this.selectedLevel.push(obj);
    console.log('grade', this.selectedLevel);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a lot easier this way:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Grade</mat-label>
    <mat-select placeholder="Grade" aria-label="Grade" formControlName="Grade" (selectionChange)="selectedGrade($event)"
        multiple required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let s of gradeCodes" [value]="s.Code">
            <!-- If name is undefined it won't display a thing -->
            <span>{{s.Name}}</span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

selectedGrade(event: any) {
    const code: number = event.value[0];
    const grade = this.gradeCodes.find(grade => grade.code === code)
    const obj = {
        code: code,
        level: grade.Name
    }
    this.selectedLevel = [...this.selectedLevel, obj];
}
```

Remember, not changing an array reference will not trigger Angular's change detection and the data would not be displayed